# Is Sentence B wrong?

Tags: meaning

**Sentence A**: "I am to goblins what goblins are to us."

Why sentence should not written as Sentence B?

**Sentence B**: 'I am the goblins what goblins are to us."

So why sentence A use "to" instead "the"?

Answer (score 2):

The construction: '*X is to Y what Y is to Z*' (as used in sentence A) can be slightly complicated to understand technically but is nonetheless effective at concisely communicating a notion - at least between people familiar with that style of statement.

It's purpose is to inform of a relationship that exists, that is similar to another relationship. You're saying that Y is equivalent or similar/equal in effect, when applied to Z, as X is when applied to Y. Generally this would be used where somebody knows and understands the relationship between X and Y but not necessarily Y and Z.

**Some examples:**

(you develop a new cleaning formula)
"This chemical is to bacteria what a blast furnace is to butter." - Everyone knows a furnace would melt and evaporate butter away to nothing. The chemical will do the same to the bacteria.

(you -really- like chocolate)
"Chocolate is to me what water is to a parched man" - this implies that to have some chocolate would be an intense pleasure and relief.

Given this understanding. Sentence B simply doesn't make sense: the construction only works when two relationships are presented. Saying you ARE the goblins isn't a relationship.

(As per my examples it would also be more common to use four elements (Chocolate - me, water - parched man) rather than the two relationships sharing an element ('goblins' in your examples, is shared between both) But the analogy still works. So long as it is accurate to say that the effect you have upon goblins is equivalent to the effect they have upon 'us' ).

Hope that helps!